Is there a way to get S3 bucket creation date without using ListBuckets?
Is there a way to get S3 bucket creation date without using ListBuckets? I can't find another API that gives the same result.

What's wrong with using ListBuckets()? It pretty much only returns the bucket name and creation date.

There is no other way to directly retrieve the creation date of an S3 bucket without using the ListBuckets API. The ListBuckets API is the only way to retrieve the creation date of an S3 bucket.
The reason for this is that the creation date of an S3 bucket is not stored as a separate metadata property that can be retrieved using other S3 APIs. The creation date is only available as part of the response from the ListBuckets API.
